# Apache Server - Get Details of Running Config

Tags: apache

We are running Apache `httpd-2.4.6-97.0.1.el7_9` and getting some issues around MaxRequestWorkers. Once the below error was hit, Apache stopped serving requests.

```
[mpm_event:error] [pid 2248:tid 140330383964352] AH00485: scoreboard is full, not at MaxRequestWorkers
```

I am looking at getting the full runtime configuration so we can see what the values are currently set to, and in use.

FYI - The setup also has PHP-FPM which is where the main customer facing codebase is located.